# How to use navigator.sendBeacon() to execute a function?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, sendbeacon

I'm currently using a Firestore backend. What I want to achieve is to update a document on Firestore when the window closes. I know we could use `Navigator.sendBeacon()` to call an API when a window closes because it receives `url` and `data` (optional) as its parameters. However, I want to instead execute a function, for example from Firestore, there is a function called `updateDoc`. Is there a way I could achieve this?

Or is there any other approach I could use?

Comment: I have added a comment below did you managed to check it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.OnDisconnect#update) :

> There is a function  `firebase.database.onDisconnect`. The
> onDisconnect class allows you to write or clear data when your client
> disconnects from the Database server. These updates occur whether your
> client disconnects cleanly or not, so you can rely on them to clean up
> data even if a connection is dropped or a client crashes.
>
> **method [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.OnDisconnect#update):**
>
> `update ( values :  Object ,  onComplete ? :  ( a :  Error | null ) => any ) : Promise < any >`
>
> Writes multiple values at this location when the client is
> disconnected (due to closing the browser, navigating to a new page, or
> network issues).
>
> The values argument contains multiple property-value pairs that will
> be written to the Database together. Each child property can either be
> a simple property (for example, "name") or a relative path (for
> example, "name/first") from the current location to the data to
> update.
>
> As opposed to the set() method, update() can be use to selectively
> update only the referenced properties at the current location (instead
> of replacing all the child properties at the current location).
>
> See more examples using the connected version of [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#update).
>
> ```
> var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");
> ref.update({
>    onlineState: true,
>    status: "I'm online."
> });
> ref.onDisconnect().update({
>   onlineState: false,
>   status: "I'm offline."
> });
> ```

Comment: This seems to be the answer I'm looking for! However, I'm currently using web modular v9 where I use `updateDoc()` instead of `.update()`. How can I implement `onDisconnect` with `updateDoc()`? I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Comment: @Owenn I can see you have asked this question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74002533/how-to-use-ondisconnect-in-firebase-v9-reactjs) and there is already answer provided for your post.