# How to use `onDisconnect()` in Firebase v9 ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I want to update a certain document on Firestore when a user is disconnected. I'm currently using Firebase v9, so I'm using `updateDoc` to update the field. How can I achieve this with `onDisconnect`?

My function looks something like this:

```js
export async function updateUser(
  data: DocumentData,
  userId: string
): Promise<returnType> {

  return await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", userId), data)
    .then(() => {
      return { data: true, error: null };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return { data: null, error: err };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`onDisconnect()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#ondisconnect) is part of Firebase Realtime Database. If you want to update Firestore documents based on that event, then it will be best to use Cloud Functions.

Checkout [Building Presence with Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/presence) for more information.

You can still run some function locally as shown below:

```
import { onDisconnect } from "firebase/database"; 

onDisconnect(dbRef).set({}).then(() => {
  // ... 
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by `can still run some function locally` ?

Comment: @Owenn if you see the linked documentation, you can update Firestore doc in local cache but that'll not reflect for other users as you are disconnected from internet.